# super() save method on Django auth user's user change form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to edit `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm`. Basically, auth_user's user edit page.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py

According to source code, the form does not have a `save()` method, so it should inherit from `forms.ModelForm` right?

For full code, [see here](http://pastebin.com/ugbf7yek)

```
class MyUserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.id: # username and user id
            ... the rest of the __init__ is setting readonly fields

    .... some clean methods .....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = True
        user = super(MyUserAdminForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print user.username
        print 'done'
        return user
```

When I hit save, it said `'UserForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'`. I've googled quite a bit, and tried to use `add()` but didn't work. What's causing this behaviour?

The thing is: the two `print` statements are printed. But the value never saved into database. I thought that the 2nd line would have saved once already.

Thanks

Comment: Why you are replacing save method for this form? Are [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) a solution for you?

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that solution. Actually signal is a better option for this particular use case. I was just merely trying out super(). Thanks :)))

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `kwargs['commit'] = True` line and see what happen.

Django Admin would invoke `form.save_m2m()`, which is hooked to the `form` when `commit` is `False`, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L91). The unconditional overriding of `kwargs['commit'] = True` would break the `setattr` of `save_m2m()` to `form` thus `no attribute` error is raised. The actual affected logic is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L698):

```
def save_form(self, request, form, change):
     """
     Given a ModelForm return an unsaved instance. ``change`` is True if
     the object is being changed, and False if it's being added.
     """
     return form.save(commit=False)
```

You could find out that your version of `form.save()` overriding `commit=False` to `commit=True` unconditionally, thus Django Admin fails to continue as it believes `form.save(commit=False)` is invoked and thus `form.save_m2m()` needs to be called.

Refs [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has
>   a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a
>   many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a
>   form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the
>   many-to-many relation. This is because it isn't possible to save
>   many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the
>   database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using
>   commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm
>   subclass. After you've manually saved the instance produced by the
>   form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

Comment: Thanks okay. I am on my iPad so I will get back at you later on how it goes.  Misread the save part from UserCreateForm. Does all m2m save has to set to false? Also, the default value for commit is true there. What's the use case of that? Thanks.